# При нажатии на текст, он должен записываться в переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Я начинающий в *javascript*.

Мне нужно реализовать следующее:

При нажатии на текст, он должен записываться в переменную, которая находится на странице. К примеру, есть пустая переменная **date_1**. При нажатии на текст "*31.08.2017"* переменная **date_1** равна "*31.08.2017*".

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ну хоть `html` разметку приложите чтоли, и при чем тут тэг `php` ?

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```js
var date_1;
$('.copyToVar').on('click', function() {
  date_1 = $(this).text();
  console.log(date_1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span class="copyToVar">26.08.2017</span></div>
<div><span class="copyToVar">27.08.2017</span></div>
<div><span class="copyToVar">28.08.2017</span></div>
<div><span class="copyToVar">29.08.2017</span></div>
<div><span class="copyToVar">30.08.2017</span></div>
<div><span class="copyToVar">31.08.2017</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```js
var date_1;

document.getElementById('date_1').onclick = function() {
  date_1 = this.innerText;
}
```

```html
<div id='date_1'>31.08.2017</div>
```

jQuery:

```js
var date_1;

$('#date_1').click(function(){
  date_1 = $(this).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='date_1'>31.08.2017</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Более гибкий вариант. НО! имя переменной приводится в качестве строки.

```js
'use strict';
jQuery.fn.extend({
writeTo: function (variable) {
  window[variable] = this.html();
  return window[variable]
}
}); 
var myVar;
$(".block").on("click", function(){
  $(this).writeTo("myVar");
  console.log(myVar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">Мировой рекорд</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    var date;

    for(let i =  0 ; i < 10; ++i){
         document.write(`<span class="date" style="cursor:pointer">${i}</span><br>`)
    }

    for(let i =  0 ; i < 10; ++i){
    document.getElementsByClassName('date')[i].onclick = function(){
        date = document.getElementsByClassName('date')[i].innerText;
        console.log(date);
        }
    }

</script>
```